# Button click gives white screen instead of going to intended activity. Why?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm creating a multi-purpose app and part of it is a BMI Calculator. All toast messages appear correctly in the emulator and all other functionalities within the 'BMI_Calculator' Activity work. My problem is when I click the 'Calculate' button, the screen goes white and takes me back to my page of buttons pictured below:

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEXPt.png)

I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwlHCUiwMco&list=RDCMUCO-vqQSN1N9unBqDHfL45TA&index=3 and his all works.

Logcat gives this error:

```
2022-04-23 18:27:13.476 21383-21414/com.example.assignment_2 E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1
```

BMI_Calculator.java

```
public class BMI_Calculator extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button CalcBMI;

    TextView CurHeight, CurAge, CurWeight;
    ImageView IAge, IWeight, DWeight, DAge;
    SeekBar HeightSB;

    RelativeLayout M, F;

    int WeightIT = 55;
    int AgeIT = 12;
    int CurProgress;

    String ProgressIT = "170";
    String UserType = "0";
    String Weight2 = "55";
    String Age2 = "12";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bmi_calculator);

        CalcBMI = findViewById(R.id.calculate_bmi);

        CurAge = findViewById(R.id.current_age);
        CurWeight = findViewById(R.id.current_weight);
        CurHeight = findViewById(R.id.current_height);

        IAge = findViewById(R.id.increase_age);
        DAge = findViewById(R.id.decrease_age);
        IWeight = findViewById(R.id.increment_weight);
        DWeight = findViewById(R.id.decrease_weight);
        HeightSB = findViewById(R.id.height_seek_bar);

        M = findViewById(R.id.male);
        F = findViewById(R.id.female);

        M.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                M.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.male_female_focus));
                F.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.male_female_not_focus));
                UserType = "Male";
            }
        });

        F.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                F.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.male_female_focus));
                M.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.male_female_not_focus));
                UserType = "Female";
            }
        });

        HeightSB.setMax(214);
        HeightSB.setProgress(170);
        HeightSB.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b) {
                CurProgress = progress;
                ProgressIT = String.valueOf(CurProgress);
                CurHeight.setText(ProgressIT);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        IAge.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AgeIT=AgeIT+1;
                Age2=String.valueOf(AgeIT);
                CurAge.setText(Age2);
            }
        });

        IWeight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                WeightIT=WeightIT+1;
                Weight2=String.valueOf(WeightIT);
                CurWeight.setText(Weight2);
            }
        });

        DWeight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                WeightIT=WeightIT-1;
                Weight2=String.valueOf(WeightIT);
                CurWeight.setText(Weight2);
            }
        });

        DAge.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AgeIT=AgeIT-1;
                Age2=String.valueOf(AgeIT);
                CurAge.setText(Age2);
            }
        });

       CalcBMI.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(UserType.equals("0"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Select Your Gender!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                else if(ProgressIT.equals("0"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Select Your Height!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(AgeIT==0 || AgeIT<0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Incorrect Age. Try Again!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(WeightIT==0 || WeightIT<0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Incorrect Weight. Try Again!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    { final Intent intent8 = new Intent();
                    intent8.putExtra("gender",UserType);
                    intent8.putExtra("height",ProgressIT);
                    intent8.putExtra("weight",Weight2);
                    intent8.putExtra("age",Age2);

                        intent8.setClass(BMI_Calculator.this, BMI_Result.class);
                        CalcBMI.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                startActivity(intent8);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Initialize and assign variable
        BottomNavigationView BNV = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

        // Perform item selected listener
        BNV.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.MindItem:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Mind.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.HomeItem:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.BodyItem:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Body.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.bmi_tb);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            switch (id) {
                case R.id.TimerItem:
                    Intent i = new Intent(BMI_Calculator.this, Timer.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    return true;
                case R.id.SettingsItem:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BMI_Calculator.this, Settings.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;

                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

BMI_Result.java

```
public class BMI_Result extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button ReBMI;

    TextView BMIDisplay, Category, G;
    Intent i6, i7;
    ImageView mimageview;

    String BMI;
    float BMI_NT;

    String height;
    String weight;
    float heightINT, weightINT;
    RelativeLayout mbackground;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bmi_result);

        i6 = getIntent();
        BMIDisplay = findViewById(R.id.bmidisplay);
        Category = findViewById(R.id.bmicategory);
        G = findViewById(R.id.genderdisplay);
        mbackground.findViewById(R.id.contentlayout);
        mimageview = findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        height = i6.getStringExtra("height");
        weight = i6.getStringExtra("weight");

        heightINT = Float.parseFloat(height);
        weightINT = Float.parseFloat(weight);

        heightINT = heightINT / 100;

        BMI_NT = weightINT / (heightINT * heightINT);

        BMI = Float.toString(BMI_NT);

        if (BMI_NT < 16) {
            Category.setText("SEVERE THINNESS");
            mbackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            mimageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.cross);
        } else if (BMI_NT < 16.9 && BMI_NT > 16) {
            Category.setText("MODERATE THINNESS");
            mbackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            mimageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.warning);
        } else if (BMI_NT < 18.4 && BMI_NT > 17) {
            Category.setText("MILD THINNESS");
            mbackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            mimageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.warning);
        } else if (BMI_NT < 25 && BMI_NT > 18.4) {
            Category.setText("NORMAL");
            mbackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            mimageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
        } else if (BMI_NT < 29.4 && BMI_NT > 25) {
            Category.setText("OVERWEIGHT");
            mbackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            mimageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.warning);
        } else {
            Category.setText("OBESE");
            mbackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            mimageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.warning);
        }

        G.setText(i6.getStringExtra("gender"));
        BMIDisplay.setText(BMI);

        ReBMI = findViewById(R.id.recalculate_bmi);

        ReBMI.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i7 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BMI_Calculator.class);
                startActivity(i7);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

I've looked through and can't find anything wrong. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check console logcat for exception raised?

Answer (score 0):

In your CalcBMI.setOnClickListener you are redeclaring the same listener inside itself.

try replacing the else { in your CalcBMI.setOnClickListener with the following.

```
else {
    final Intent intent8 = new Intent(this, BMI_Result.class);
    intent8.putExtra("gender", UserType);
    intent8.putExtra("height", ProgressIT);
    intent8.putExtra("weight", Weight2);
    intent8.putExtra("age", Age2);
    startActivity(intent8);
}
```